# when if(a) will return true in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am new to Verilog and I had been asked the following question:

Consider `a = reg[3:0]`, then what values can `a` have so `if(a)` will return `true`?
I have no idea where to start, tried to compile some examples but all failed `syntax problem`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing `if (a)` is the same as writing `if (a !=0)`. Since `a` is a 4-bit variable, you can expand that out to `if (a[0] != 0 | a[1] ! = 0 | a[2] != 0 | a[3] !=0)`. So a 1 in any bit position makes the expression true. Note that an unknown value `x` or `z` as an operand with the equality/inequality operators results in an unknown and is considered false. But an unknown or'ed with true is true.

Answer (score 0):

`reg` is a verilog keyword used to declare variable types, and the expression you provided is an **illegal** verilog expression. You can declare `a` to be a 4-bit reg as the following:

```
reg[3:0] a;
```

the above makes `a` a 4-bit vector. Now, verilog bits might have 4 states: `0`, `1`, `x`, and `z`. So, any one of 4 bits of `a` can be in any of those states. Now you have 256 possible combinations. If you ignore `x` and `z` states, you can get 16 combinations expressed in decimals as 0 to 15.

`true` means that at least one bit in `a` is `1`.  In all other cases it will be false.